# When I return a double from a function it becomes a integer?

Tags: c++

Under the function `distance`, I return a `double` called `distan`. But when I go back to the `main` function, and the `dis1[i]` becomes an integer. For example, if `distan`=6.06, the `dis1[i]` will just be 6 when I debug it.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int distance(double x1,double x2,double y1,double y2){
    double k;
    k=pow((x1-x2),2)+pow((y1-y2),2);
    double distan;
    distan=sqrt(k);
    return distan;  
}
int main() {
    int n,k;

    double dis=0.00;
    cin>>n;
    double points[2][100]={0.0};
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int m=0;m<2;m++){
        cin>>points[m][i];}
    }
    double dis1[100]={0.0};
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(int r=1;r<n;r++&&count++)
        dis1[count]=distance(points[0][i],points[0][i+r],points[1][i],points[1][i+r]);

    }

    for(int i=0;i<=count;i++){
        if(dis1[i]>dis){
            dis=dis1[i];
        }
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << dis << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Plus, this code is to calculate the biggest distance from two sets of points(x and y). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your return type of function `distance`, it is `int`, change it to `double`

Answer (score 3):

The `distance` function's return type is `int`:

```
int distance(double x1,double x2,double y1,double y2){
^^^
```

Change that to `double` if you want to return a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

change your function like as following....

```
double distance(double x1,double x2,double y1,double y2){
    double k;
    k=pow((x1-x2),2)+pow((y1-y2),2);
    double distan;
    distan=sqrt(k);
    return distan;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when u return the double value to funtion then the funtion return type should be double if u required double.

**double** distance(double x1,double x2,double y1,double y2)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your function for the **Return type** and you're done.

```
double distance(double x1,double x2,double y1,double y2){
    double k;
    k=pow((x1-x2),2)+pow((y1-y2),2);
    double distan;
    distan=sqrt(k);
    return distan;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The double is coerced to an integer in the last line of the integer function "distance":

```
return distan;
```

...That is where it becomes an integer. Your compiler should give you a warning when doing implicit type coercion. Even better are languages that don't do that.